# Pandas code equivalent for below SQL of sample data

Tags: python, sql, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

**Request:** Need pandas equivalent for data frame having below sample data

**Details:** Query to fetch the records of strike which are less than lastPrice for Status "NearHigh" and order the rows partitioning symbol with an order of strikes in descending order, reverse the logic if status is "NearLow"

---

**Sample Data**

```
|symbol|lastPrice|Status|tradingsymbol|expiry|strike|lot_size|instrument_type|
|APOLLOHOSP|4090.35|NearHigh|APOLLOHOSP21AUG3700PE|26-08-2021|3700|250|PE|
|APOLLOHOSP|4090.35|NearHigh|APOLLOHOSP21AUG3750CE|26-08-2021|3750|250|CE|
|APOLLOHOSP|4090.35|NearHigh|APOLLOHOSP21AUG3750PE|26-08-2021|3750|250|PE|
|APOLLOHOSP|4090.35|NearHigh|APOLLOHOSP21AUG3800CE|26-08-2021|3800|250|CE|
|APOLLOHOSP|4090.35|NearHigh|APOLLOHOSP21AUG3800PE|26-08-2021|3800|250|PE|
|APOLLOHOSP|4090.35|NearHigh|APOLLOHOSP21AUG3850CE|26-08-2021|3850|250|CE|
|APOLLOHOSP|4090.35|NearHigh|APOLLOHOSP21AUG3850PE|26-08-2021|3850|250|PE|
|APOLLOHOSP|4090.35|NearHigh|APOLLOHOSP21AUG3900CE|26-08-2021|3900|250|CE|
|APOLLOHOSP|4090.35|NearHigh|APOLLOHOSP21AUG3900PE|26-08-2021|3900|250|PE|
|APOLLOHOSP|4090.35|NearHigh|APOLLOHOSP21AUG3950CE|26-08-2021|3950|250|CE|
|APOLLOHOSP|4090.35|NearHigh|APOLLOHOSP21AUG3950PE|26-08-2021|3950|250|PE|
|APOLLOHOSP|4090.35|NearHigh|APOLLOHOSP21AUG4000CE|26-08-2021|4000|250|CE|
|APOLLOHOSP|4090.35|NearHigh|APOLLOHOSP21AUG4000PE|26-08-2021|4000|250|PE|
|APOLLOHOSP|4090.35|NearHigh|APOLLOHOSP21AUG4050CE|26-08-2021|4050|250|CE|
|APOLLOHOSP|4090.35|NearHigh|APOLLOHOSP21AUG4050PE|26-08-2021|4050|250|PE|
|IDEA|7.35|NearLow|IDEA21AUG6CE|26-08-2021|6|70000|CE|
|IDEA|7.35|NearLow|IDEA21AUG6PE|26-08-2021|6|70000|PE|
|IDEA|7.35|NearLow|IDEA21AUG7CE|26-08-2021|7|70000|CE|
|IDEA|7.35|NearLow|IDEA21AUG7PE|26-08-2021|7|70000|PE|
|IDEA|7.35|NearLow|IDEA21AUG8CE|26-08-2021|8|70000|CE|
|IDEA|7.35|NearLow|IDEA21AUG8PE|26-08-2021|8|70000|PE|
|IDEA|7.35|NearLow|IDEA21AUG9CE|26-08-2021|9|70000|CE|
|IDEA|7.35|NearLow|IDEA21AUG9PE|26-08-2021|9|70000|PE|
```

**SQL for getting the desired output**

```
select tradingsymbol, expiry, symbol, lastPrice, Status, strike, lot_size, instrument_type,
row_number() over(partition by symbol order by case when Status='NearHigh' then strike desc else strike asc end) as rnk
from Table
where instrument_type = case when Status='NearHigh' then 'PE' else 'CE' end
and instrument_type = case when Status='NearHigh' then strike < lastPrice else strike > lastPrice end
```

**Desired Output**

```
|symbol|lastPrice|Status|tradingsymbol|expiry|strike|lot_size|instrument_type|rnk|
|APOLLOHOSP|4090.35|NearHigh|APOLLOHOSP21AUG3700PE|26-08-2021|3700|250|PE|8|
|APOLLOHOSP|4090.35|NearHigh|APOLLOHOSP21AUG3750PE|26-08-2021|3750|250|PE|7|
|APOLLOHOSP|4090.35|NearHigh|APOLLOHOSP21AUG3800PE|26-08-2021|3800|250|PE|6|
|APOLLOHOSP|4090.35|NearHigh|APOLLOHOSP21AUG3850PE|26-08-2021|3850|250|PE|5|
|APOLLOHOSP|4090.35|NearHigh|APOLLOHOSP21AUG3900PE|26-08-2021|3900|250|PE|4|
|APOLLOHOSP|4090.35|NearHigh|APOLLOHOSP21AUG3950PE|26-08-2021|3950|250|PE|3|
|APOLLOHOSP|4090.35|NearHigh|APOLLOHOSP21AUG4000PE|26-08-2021|4000|250|PE|2|
|APOLLOHOSP|4090.35|NearHigh|APOLLOHOSP21AUG4050PE|26-08-2021|4050|250|PE|1|
|IDEA|7.35|NearLow|IDEA21AUG8CE|26-08-2021|8|70000|CE|1|
|IDEA|7.35|NearLow|IDEA21AUG9CE|26-08-2021|9|70000|CE|2|
|IDEA|7.35|NearLow|IDEA21AUG10CE|26-08-2021|10|70000|CE|3|
```